# How to save vegan::simper() output to data table

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to save `vegan::simper()` output as a data frame so that I can filter objects and eventually export as a table for publication. However the simper output is of class = list and I'm not sure how to convert this to a data frame. Here is some sample code using Dune.

```
# Species and environmental data
dune <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.spe.txt', row.names = 1)

dune.env <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.env.txt', row.names = 1)

data(dune)
data(dune.env)
(sim <- with(dune.env, simper(dune, Management)))
summary(sim)
class(sim)
```

Comment: You cannot since the result is returned as a list of many data bases showing different aspects of the data. Decide what you want your tables to look like and extract the data frames you need to produce those tables. Read the manual page carefully, especially the paragraph that begins "The results of simper can be very difficult to interpret and they are often misunderstood even in publications."

Answer (score 0):

To complement the comment by @dcarlson: `simper` result object is a complicated beast and there is no easy way of getting a table – especially as I don't know what kind of table you are looking for. The result object stores every pair of factor classes in a separate table. You can extract all those tables with `summary(sim)`. If you want to see only one table, for instance for the pair `SF_HF`, use

```r
summary(sim)$SF_HF
```

(and to see available names, use `names(sim)`). Then it is up to you collect the table you desire from these individual tables. All information is there.

And read the warnings in the manual page.

If you want to get something similar as the short printed output, look at `vegan:::print.simper` to see how it can be done.